# actionlink not resolving urls related to route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following route ( it's the first in my global.asax )

```
    routes.MapRoute(
    "AdminCompany",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{companyId}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", companyId = "", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
    );
```

if i navigation to

"Order/DisplayAdmin/2/79000180" it resolves correctly

However if i do the following

```
Html.ActionLink("View", "DisplayAdmin", new {companyId = Model.CompanyId, id = order.OrderNumber }, new { @class = "button add" })
```

it displays

/Order.aspx/DisplayAdmin/39068760?companyId=0

which also works, but isn't so pretty :)

Here is my Controller Method

```
   public ActionResult DisplayAdmin(int companyId, [DefaultValue(0)]int id, [DefaultValue(0)] int orderItemStatusId)
        {
            var viewModel = DisplayAdminViewModel(companyId, id, _statusResponses);
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

Am i calling ActionLink the wrong way? how do i get the nice Urls?

Comment: Try a RouteLink equivalent to check if the url is correctly generated. The Route debugger from http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx will most definitely help in identifying which how the routes are matched to your URLs.

Answer (score 1):

only thing I can think of that is happening is that its falling back to the Default route, I did a copy paste of both your route and the html.ActionLink and it works perfectly for me displaying it like "/Order.aspx/DisplayAdmin/39068760/45456", i did replicate the same fault like you get if the naming isn't the same in the route and action link.

Comment: Can you please expand on "the naming isn't the same in the route and action link."?

Comment: if the route parameters has a certain name, those exact names must be used in the actionlink for it to work properly. that was what I meant, I can see that it was unclear the way I said it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the overload of ActionLink that has a RouteValueDictionary argument.

It appears that you are currently using the overload with the "object" argument and it's going to a workable, but not as clean, url.